# Grape or normal import

Tags: groovy, import, gpars, groovy-grape

Does it make a difference, how to integrate GPars in my projects?
Can I either do

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.gpars', module='gpars', version='1.0.0')
```

or just (provided I have all the required jars in my build path)

```
import groovyx.gpars.*
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depending on how you organize your project and what is your build system.

If it's a plain Groovy script, using a `@Grab` annotation and `import` statements **together** will be working for you.
`@Grab` just tells the system to manage dependencies, and you still need `import` statements.

But if it's a bigger project, using [Gradle](http://gradle.org) is the better way.